# Match string using regex which includes vertical bar

Tags: regex

I have:

```
|123|456|789|
```

I can capture only `|123|` using regex

```
\|(\d*)\|
```

But not sure how to capture the full string. I am quite new to this.

I will be thankful for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
^\|(\d*\|?)*
```

This should work. Start with vertical bar and repeat numbers and optional vertical bar.

Comment: Why capture the last bar?

Comment: But it also captures |123|456|789. Changed it to ^\|(\d*\|)*, and worked fine. Thanks a lot James

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
^\|[\d|]*
```

- `^\|` matches literal `|` at start, as `|` is a Regex token we need to escape it
- `[\d|]*` matches any number of digits or `|`, `|` inside `[]` is treated literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xT2fI2/1)

---

From comment, if there must be a `|` at the end, do:

```
^\|[\d|]*\|$
```

Comment: It does capture |123|456|789, which is not expected. It should be |123|456|789|

Comment: @black You mean there must be a `|` at the end? If so, the fix is easy, do `^\|[\d|]*\|$`

Answer (score 0):

```css
input:valid{
background-color:green;
}

input:invalid{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^[\|123\|]*$" value="|123|">
<br/>
<input type="text" pattern="^[\|\0-9\|]*$" value="|123|">
```